# Ethernet Connection Drops from Router - Un/Replugging Cable Fixes

Tags: ethernet, home-networking, rj-45

I recently added an ethernet line that runs though some walls to link a microserver and some RPis in one room with the main router in another room.

I have a problem where after some (seemingly random) time (could be hours, could be days) the connection is lost. The activity light on the router goes off and I cannot connect to the microserver at the other end. The only fix seems to be to unplug and replug(?) the ethernet cable at the router. Then this paragraph repeats.

At first I thought it might be the crappy SkyQ hub, so I replaced that. Certainly Internet reliability has improved but that's a separate issue. But unfortunately the same ethernet connection keeps dropping.

I have resettled the ethernet individual cables in the wall socket. I have checked continuity with an ethernet checker thing... You plug in both ends and it just cycles flashing lights showing each wire is connected.

So before I replace the cabling running through the walls I am asking if there is anything I can test first?

Hardware is connected like so:

Router > Ethernet Cable > RJ45 wall socket > Ethernet cable running through several walls > RJ45 wall socket > ethernet cable > switch > ethernet cable to microserver.

I strongly think it's the wiring in the wall but it's the most effort to change if it's not the problem.

Comment: Hi, if you use a laptop wired to the router does it still disconnects? I'll try checking this way to rule out the router. Stuff like this happened with my old D-link router, I thought that cables even my pc was at fault. It turned out it was the router.

Comment: What category of cable is it? About how long is it? What speed is it running at (fast ethernet, gigabit?). Are you 100% sure it's wired to a standard like 568B? Incorrect pair-to-pin mappings (even if the same on both sides) will definitely do this at gigabit speeds.

Comment: Definitely low quality cable.